# Argument types of read() for file handling in c++

Tags: c++

Assume customer is a struct, and `savac` is a variable of this type.

The call to `read()` is

```
read((char *) &savac,sizeof(customer));
```

Why is there a need to type cast to a character array?

Comment: Depends on type of `savac`. If it's `char` then no need casting.

Comment: The POSIX `read()` function takes 3 rather than 2 arguments and doesn't require casting to `char*` as it takes a `void*`. What's the signature of your `read()` function?

Comment: *The syntax to read is...*  -- Note that that line of code should only be used to read into trivial types / structs.  You cannot read into non-POD types using that method.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you can, but it's UB.  However, UB can be an acceptable part of a design as long as it is accepted and dealt with.  UB isn't nasal demons.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o

Comment: This is not syntax, it is semantics.

Answer (score 0):

`istream::read` expects to receive an argument of type `pointer to char`.

If you need/want to read data into an object of some other type, you  need to convert the address of that object to a pointer to char so `read` can accept it.

Also note that in most cases, when you're writing C++ you'd prefer to use one of the "new" (not really so new any more) C++ style casts instead of a C-style cast. A C-style cast does work, but C++ casts are more restricted, and therefore generally a little bit safer.

Comment: The use of `read` by the OP points to use of `istream::read`. If that is the case, then the expected argument type is `char*`, not `void*`.